# MVVM Light in Class Library...something is holding onto the ViewModelLocator when I free all associated views

Tags: mvvm-light

Using Ninject and MVVM-Light in a Class Library DLL. When I free up all Views that call for the DataContext

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
</UserControl.Resources>   

<UserControl.DataContext>
  <Binding Path="DataViewsViewModel" Source="{StaticResource ViewModelLocator}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

...it appears to NOT release the ViewModelLocator.

Using ANTS Memory Profiler, the only references remaining are to the ViewModelLocator.

I suppose more detail is in order, and would welcome any guidance on what information is most beneficial to resolve this issue. I am learning on the fly here :).

What I'm trying to accomplish is the complete Cleanup of an instance of a class object so that when a new one is instantiated it will start completely new.

p.s. this Class Library is our way of adding WPF into an MFC C++ application. We are calling up "controls" as needed and want to completely cleanup or dispose when no longer needed.

Comment: Because this is a DLL, my research indicated that I could not spin up the ViewModelLocator from the App.xaml. So each Xaml view has a resource pointing to a ResourceDictionary which has the following: <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>